# phone hotspot does not detect its own access point in my application

Tags: java, android, jvm-hotspot, access-point

I'm new in android programming and I don't know how to resolve in detecting access point of my phones hotspot. My application is to connect android devices via same access point, the problem is that whenever I start my phone hotspot, my application doesn't seem to read it as an access point. I want users to connect first in any access point(including my phones hotspot before going to the next activity. here's my code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
    ImageButton class3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.multiplayer);
    class3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) { //whenever this button is click

            WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);

            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (wifi.isWifiEnabled() || netInfo != null){ //connected in any access point(including own hotspot) then go to next activity   
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this.getBaseContext(), classmultiplayer.class));
            }               
        else {
            MainActivity.this.finish(); //to simplified the code i just used exit if its not connected to any acces point
        }           
        }
    });
```

**Manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

When I am connected to wifi, it works perfectly. but when I start my hotspot on my phone without any wifi connectivity it do "else statement" which is exit. I already tried some answers in stackoverflow and I don't think it solves my problem.

"just want to make sure that users are already connected to an access point before going to the next activity including its own hotspot, because I'm developing an offline multiplayer game and make them communicate with each other via same access points".

there is already an existing android application that can do this, I just want to apply it on my app. Please answer..